# Contributions of a problematic team member to an open source project

Tags: licensing, project-management, teamwork, management, copyright

I'm currently coordinating the development of a software for a certain scientific computational task. The developers are all working on the project on a voluntary basis. Our goal is to publish the software as free software once it is done. The whole project is being developed in an academic establishment, where I'm the only employed and the other are students. There is no connection with courses, grades and what so ever. Just a bunch of people working towards a common goal. There is no contract as well.

The project is still at the beginning, but there is already some non-trivial code implemented.

The thing is that one of the developers is starting to delay the implementation of the project due to personal problems with another developer. For instance, refusing to communicate, writing emails with personal rants, etc.

I have the following related questions.

1. If I remove the problematic developer from the project, does he have any rights to the code?
2. Can he refuse to let the software become open software?
3. What is the best way to acknowledge his contribution? Until now he has been involved in a fair part of the coding. But since there is so much to be done yet, his contribution may be about 5% of the implemented code.
4. Does it help, if we just dump the part he implemented and redo it using different techniques?

Comment: We don't provide HR advice here, sorry.  Try http://workplace.stackexchange.com, but *read their site instructions first.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey despite the title the question is not about HR but about licensing and copyright.

Comment: Those subjects are off-topic too.

Comment: There are also several other sites, such as Project Management pm.stackexchange.com and Academia academia.stackexchange.com However, please read their site instructions first, especially on what is on-topic and off-topic.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [What's the default license of code published at GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4007674/1796930) and [Choose a License › No License](https://choosealicense.com/no-license/)

Answer (score 2):

> There is no contract

You are screwed. Each developer owns the copyright to their work.

You need to get them all to sign some sort of contribution agreement to give up copyright and/or to licence their code to you in such a way as you can publish it under an open source licence.

Do this **immediately** because even if you remove all the disputed code, proving it in court will be next to impossible and it will kill the project.

If any developer refuses; scrap the entire project and start something completely different.

You have really let everyone down by not sorting this stuff out on day 1.

Comment: Immediately: Because either he signs, then you're fine, or he doesn't sign, then the earlier you know, the better.

Answer (score 1):

This question raises some legal matters related to copyright and licensing.  Legal matters depend very much of your jurisdiction, and existing agreements.  The safest would be to consult a lawyer or a qualified legal expert in your jurisdiction.

The following thoughts based on my experience as software engineer and shall not be considered as legal advise:

1. [Each author](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234125/who-has-right-over-the-code-that-comes-from-contributions-in-an-open-source-proj) in such a joint project is in principle [owner of his contributions](http://asp-software.org/www/misv_resources/business-articles/who-owns-the-code/) to the code.  *Possible exception: if the contribution is made as employee, code might be owned by employer, depending on work contract and jurisdiction.*
2. If the developper joined the project and already agreed to open source under an already agreed open source license, there are chances that his contribution is already available to you under the terms of that license.  However, if this was not so far agreed, he could object to open source.  FUrthermore, even if it's agreed, in case of a dispute you'd have to prove that he agreed to the terms, which might be difficult.
3. Can't answer, and depends on the agreed license scheme.  In principle he should appear in the contributor list.  You could also foresee an [additional contributor agreement](https://opensource.guide/legal/#does-my-project-need-an-additional-contributor-agreement).
4. In the worst case, you could indeed consider to remove his code and replace it with your own code using different techniques.  However, there is still a risk that in case of litigation your production could be considered as [a non-literal copy](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20170202/11372736614/how-is-non-literally-copying-code-still-copyright-infringement.shtml).  This is a very delicate topic, but the principle would be that it can be demonstrated that you make a paraphrase of the former code and copy the abstract structure of that code.

Here some additional reading:

- [Copyright in Open Source Software – Understanding the Boundaries](http://www.ifosslr.org/ifosslr/article/view/30/64).  In-depth article, with different scenarios of contribution.  You'll discover for example that in some cases, when a team designs and code together, so that it's difficult to put individual contributions apart, there can be a joint ownership of the whole code
- [Legal side of open source](https://opensource.guide/legal/) some general knowledge good to know for anybody intending to start an open source project.